# How to add an admin user to sudoers on Big Sur

Tags: terminal, big-sur, sudo, administrator

I am running Big Sur on a MacBook Pro and am unable to run `su` or `sudo` in a terminal window despite being logged into an Admin (and Mobile) account. I always get the error: `<username> is not in the sudoers file`.

Here is a transcript:

```
mac-947:~ spertus$ visudo
visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
mac-947:~ spertus$ sudo visudo
Password:
spertus is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
mac-947:~ spertus$ sudo su
Password:
spertus is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
mac-947:~ spertus$ sudo -s su
Password:
spertus is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
mac-947:~ spertus$ sudo -i spertus su
Password:
spertus is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

As suggested in a comment to [macOS - User can perform admin tasks but cannot sudo](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382116/macos-user-can-perform-admin-tasks-but-cannot-sudo), I tried granting Full Disk Access to the terminal app, but that didn't help. I also tried the answers in [Cannot su to Admin on Big Sur](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/426393/cannot-su-to-admin-on-big-sur#) without success.

This shows that I am logged into an account in the Admin group:
[image: Screenshot of Users & Groups settings showing Ellen Spertus (spertus) in groups Admin, Mobile]

How can I add my account to the sudoers file (or otherwise run with root privileges)?

My question differs from [I don't have administrator account on my mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac) because my account is in the Admin group, as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Using single-user mode as suggested in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/218580/182183 should at least get you closer to the answer. You might also want to try creating a new user (with admin privileges)

Comment: There are several possible causes here, and without some troubleshooting to find out what's wrong, it's impossible to say how to fix it. The /etc/sudoers file should have a line that says "`%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL`", which means any member of the `admin` group is allowed to run any command as any user. One possibility is that there's something weird about your account that makes `sudo` think it's not in the admin group; creating a new admin account is a good way to test this. After that, looking at the /etc/sudoers file to see if that line is there would be the next thing I'd check.

Comment: EVen though your problem is slightly different than the linked question, the answer applies as well: you need to create a new admin user and then fix `/etc/sudoers`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try create a new Admin User.

On Big Sur the following method works fine :

You boot in Recovery Mode. (cmd+r at boot) .

If Filevault is activated, from Disk Utility, you unlock/mount the System Volume giving the password. (right click on the system volume).

You quit disk utility, then on top menu you select Utilities/Terminal

I suppose the System Volume name is "Macintosh HD", the command is :

```
rm /Volumes/"Macintosh HD"/var/db/.AppleSetupDone
```

If no error message you reboot the Mac and then you will be invited to create a new administrator.

Then you may be could repair the currents Users.

Comment: Thank you, but I am already an Admin user.

Comment: Sûre, but your admin has a problem with  the sudoers file. Maybe a new user administrator created by the system can help you. Have you modify this file?